# can a wave on rope placed away from gravity go on forever?

Tags: waves

we can make waves on a rope like we produce waves on a whip. assume that my rope(which is pretty long) is in space and i produce a wave on it at a point the rope is connected at the two ends. would the wave go through the rope forever. would the wave repeat?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

No real material is perfectly elastic. By this I mean that if we bend a real material then let it relax we do not get as much energy out as we have put in. The missing energy is dissipated as heat. So the wave initially present in your rope would decay, and its energy would end up making the rope hotter.

If we could come up with some hypothetical perfectly elastic material then the wave would continue circulating forever. Well, almost. In principle the wave would radiate tiny amounts of gravitational waves and eventually die down, though the timescales for this would be enormous. There is a related question [Would a pendulum swing indefinitely in a frictionless vacuum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69013/would-a-pendulum-swing-indefinitely-in-a-frictionless-vacuum).

Comment: thank you for your answer, can u tell me this.if we add another wave on the opposite direction with the same characteristics such as amplitude and all what would happen?

Comment: @SCK: if the rope is linear, i.e. deformation is proportional to stress, then the waves will not interact so both will continue circling without changing. If the rope is non-linear then the waves will interact and change shape. Exactly what will happen would depend on the stress-strain curve of the rope and the shape of the wave, and it would be quite a complicated thing to calculate.

Comment: "In principle the wave would radiate tiny amounts of gravitational waves and eventually die down" what did you mean by this, does every moving body radiates tiny amount of gravitational feild? @John Rennie

Comment: @SCK: in principle any distribution of matter that has a time dependant quadrupole moment will radiate gravitational waves. In practice this radiation is vanishingly small in everyday life.

Comment: i don't know much about this stuff so let me ask , as you said the wave will die down after a very long time, if the same would happen to a moving body, wouldn't it contradict newton's first law? @John Rennie

Comment: @SCK: a body moving in a straight line at constant velocity doesn't have a time dependant quadropole moment so it won't radiate gravitational waves. See [the definition of quadrupole moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole).